# General Grover's search showing wrong results on a particular instance

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

I am trying to implement a general Grover's search for `n` qubits searching for `m` marked elements. I happened to observe that for the case of multiple solutions, I could stack together the oracles for each marked state and the result would be phase flip of each marked state. For example, for marked states `00` and `10`,I would design an oracle for both of them and stack them together. Same goes for higher qubits and more marked elements. Then I designed a general diffusion circuit. I'm then iterating the oracle and diffusion circuits `T` times, where `T` is given by
$$
T = \Bigg\lfloor{\frac{\pi\cdot k}{4\arcsin\sqrt{m/N}}}\Bigg\rfloor
$$

The problem is I'm getting correct results for almost every other state except `n=3` qubits and `m=4` solutions. I am taking marked states to be `marked = [ '111', '010', '011', '000']` and the results I am getting from running the circuit through qasm simulator is not what I expect:[image: Obtained histogram plot]

This is the code I wrote:

```
#Define and initialize the circuit

#Number of qubits
n = 3

#Define and initialize circuit
q = QuantumRegister(n, 'q')
c = ClassicalRegister(n ,'c')
ckt = QuantumCircuit(q, c)

#Put all initial states into superposition
ckt.h(q)

#Define the marked item

marked = [ '111', '010', '011', '000']
m = len(marked)

#Implement the oracle function for given marked item
#Checked, correct

def oracle(ckt, marked):

    for j in marked:
    
    #Put a X-gate for 0 qubits
        for i in range(len(j)):
            if j[i] == '0':
                ckt.x(q[i])

        #Implement a multi-controlled Z-gate
        ckt.h(q[n-1])
        ckt.mcx([q[i] for i in range(len(j)-1)], q[n-1])
        ckt.h(q[n-1])

        #Put X gates on those states that were acted upon by X-gates before
        for i in range(len(j)):
            if j[i] == '0':
                ckt.x(q[i])


#Implement the diffuser function

def diffuser(ckt):
    #Hadamard on all qubits
    ckt.h(q)

    #X-gates on all qubits
    ckt.x(q)

    #MCZ gate
    ckt.h(q[n-1])
    ckt.mcx([q[i] for i in range(n-1)], q[n-1])
    ckt.h(q[n-1])

    #X-gate on all qubits again
    ckt.x(q)

    #H-gates on all qubits again
    ckt.h(q)

#Set number of iterations

import math
import numpy as np

N = 2**n

def T(k):
    return math.floor((np.pi*k)/(4*np.arcsin(math.sqrt(m/N))))

k = 1

while True:
    if T(k) > 0:
        break
    else:
        k = k + 2
iterations = T(k)

#Iterate the circuit for 'iterations' times

for i in range(iterations):
    oracle(ckt, marked)
    diffuser(ckt)
```

I would really appreciate someone telling me the reason for this malfunction.

Comment: See here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21806/9474

Answer (score 1):

Grover's Algorithm doesn't work when the number of valid solutions is exactly half the number of possibilities, similar behavior should be seen for 2 qubits and 2 solutions and 4 qubits and 8 solutions and so on. Given an oracle $O$ of this sort that is guaranteed to leave each computational basis state either unchanged or phase flipped, a quantum state $|\phi\rangle$ can be written in the form $|\phi\rangle = \cos(\theta)|s'\rangle + \sin(\theta)|\omega\rangle$ where $|s'\rangle$ and $|\omega\rangle$ are two unit vectors such that $|s'\rangle$ is unaffected by the oracle and $|\omega\rangle$ is flipped. If $B$ are the computational basis states unaffected by the oracle and $P$ the ones flipped, then $|s'\rangle = \sum_{k \in B}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n - m}}|k\rangle$ and $|\omega\rangle = \sum_{k \in P}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}|k\rangle$ allows the uniform superposition $|s\rangle = \sum_{k = 0}^{2^n - 1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}|k\rangle$ to be written as $|s\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{2^n - m}{2^n}}|s'\rangle + \sqrt{m/2^n}|\omega\rangle$.

The relevance of this is that, for the net Grover iteration operator $G = (2|s\rangle\langle s| - I)O$, performing $q$ iterations on $|s\rangle$ gives $G^q|s\rangle = \cos((2q + 1)\theta)|s'\rangle + \sin((2q + 1)\theta)|\omega\rangle$ (the oracle flips across $|s'\rangle$ and the diffusion across $|s\rangle$, leading to a net rotation double-opposite of that of rotating from $|s\rangle$ to $|s'\rangle$ see [this diagram for the base idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm#/media/File:Grovers_algorithm_geometry.png)) where $\theta$ is such that $|s\rangle = \cos(\theta)|s'\rangle + \sin(\theta)|\omega\rangle$. The value of $\theta$ for $n$ qubits and $m$ solutions is $\arcsin(\sqrt{m/2^n})$. If $m = 2^{n -1}$, this implies $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$, and thus $q$ Grover iterations will lead to the coefficient of $|\omega\rangle$ being $\sin(\frac{(2q + 1)\pi}{4})$, which will always give a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answer. However, I am still seeing 'equal' type of histogram (like a superimposed state) if I take these marked states: marked = ['000', '001', '010', '100', '110', '101']. Is there any justification for this or there is something wrong with my reasoning/code?

Comment: In that case $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and doing 3n + 1 iterations for an integer n will ironically give a theoretical 100% chance of measuring a non-marked state (essentially since there are more marked states then unmarked and only relative phase matters, the unmarked ones function as marked) while 3n + 2 and 3n iterations will keep even probabilities. In that case, though, there are more right answers than wrong answers and Grover search is not necessary since a random guess will more likely than not produce a right answer.